# Use empty catch-statement or not

Tags: c#, try-catch

I have a variable of the type `int` that I want to initialize to a value from a textbox (textBox1 in the example)

Previously, I have used the second example (2). As I learned more about programming, however, I heard that using empty `catch`-statements isn’t a good idea.

I’m seeking the answer to these three questions:
Should I switch to the code in example (1)? 
Why/why not?
What’s the difference between them?

```
int myInteger;
```

What is best to use? This (1):

```
int parsedValue;
if (!int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out parsedValue))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Numbers only, please"); 
    return;
}
myInteger = parsedValue;
```

…or this (2):

```
try
{
    myInteger = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("Numbers only, please"); 
}
```

Comment: Use `int.TryParse`, don't use a `catch` for normal program flow. Btw, `TryParse` does not use `try-catch` implicitly.

Comment: Don't expect any other answers Go with @TimSchmelter

Comment: As a rule if you know that your code will throw an exception then it is better to catch it. Also if you think that by catching only the types of exceptions which you expect to occur, and which you know are safe to ignore.

Comment: Nope, @Yosi More than a preference it is matter of performance(in case of exception)

Comment: In *any* case, don't do an empty catch. At least log the error to make sure it is not a bug. Review the logs regularly.

Comment: Thank you for your comments and answers. I now have a better understanding of this thanks to you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Int.TryParse is the better solution. Why should you throw an exception if you can avoid it? If you want to cast a lot of Strings To Integer and they fail, your programm will be very slow, because Integer.TryParse is much faster than throwing an exception.

But most of all, the first one is abetter rpgoramming style!

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph's answer was also very good. But I choose to accept this because of this: "If you want to cast a lot of Strings To Integer and they fail, your programm will be very slow, because Integer.TryParse is much faster than throwing an exception."

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case, go with `TryParse`, that’s what it’s there for.

In general, an *empty* `Catch` block is indeed very bad – never do this (at the very least leave a comment to explain why the block is there and empty). But your code *isn’t* doing this: the catch block is not empty, and this usage of `Catch` is entirely fine (except that, again, in this specific case there’s a better solution).